# Why doesn't my Scheme macro work well?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want my code to transfer a struct to an expression, and evaluate it to get the original struct. Here is my code:

```
(define-syntax expr-returning (syntax-rules ()
                           ((expr-returning (car x)) '(car (expr-returning x)))
                           ((expr-returning (cdr x)) '(cdr (expr-returning x)))
                           ((expr-returning (cons x y)) '(cons (expr-returning x) (expr-returning y)))
                           ((expr-returning obj) (cond [(null? obj)  'null]
                                                       [(number? obj)  'obj]
                                                       [(char? obj)  'obj]
                                                       [(boolean? obj) 'obj]
                                                       [(pair? obj) (expr-returning (cons (car obj) (cdr obj)))]
                                                       [else 'error]
                                                  ))))
```

Here is my test:

```
(define ls (append '(a e i o u) 'y))
(define d (cons ls (cdr (cdr ls))))
(define e (expr-returning d))

d
e
(eval e)
```

The output is

```
'((a e i o u . y) i o u . y)
'(cons (expr-returning (car d1)) (expr-returning (cdr d1)))
cons: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: cons
```

What's wrong with my cons?

Comment: I tried your example in DrRacket and it works: `(eval e)` => `'((car (expr-returning d)) cdr (expr-returning d))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it doesn't make much sense since the macro expansion happens before the code runs.

```
(define-syntax expr-returning
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((expr-returning (car x)) '(car (expr-returning x)))
    ((expr-returning (cdr x)) '(cdr (expr-returning x)))
    ((expr-returning (cons x y)) '(cons (expr-returning x) (expr-returning y)))
    ((expr-returning obj) (cond [(null? obj)  'null]
                                [(number? obj)  'obj]
                                [(char? obj)  'obj]
                                [(boolean? obj) 'obj]
                                [(pair? obj) '(cons (expr-returning (car obj)) (expr-returning (cdr obj)))] ; expanded 
                                [else 'error]
                                ))))
```

And since `d` is a symbol for the macro it's `obj` and during runtime it turns into the literal expression:

```
'(cons (expr-returning (car d)) (expr-returning (cdr d)))
```

Evaluating this will trigger the expansion of expr-returning so that you actually are evaluating `(cons '(car (expr-returning d)) '(cdr (expr-returning d)))` which turns into the value `((car (expr-returning d)) . (cdr (expr-returning d)))`, displayed as `((car (expr-returning d)) cdr (expr-returning d))`

If you were to evaluate this again notice that you have `(expr-returning d)` there which indeed will do the same as before. In reality you never actually will get the structure of `d` but follow the strange loop of `d` being a pair, then follow constants, then back to the `d` being a pair.

Its trivial to make a procedure that takes a structure and produces an expression that will evaluate to something that is `equal?` to the original structure as long as you keep the structure free of those types that does not have literal versions like `#<procedure: +>` or `#<struct:bla>`. here is one supporting only pairs and numbers:

```
(define (obj->literal obj)
  (define (primitive? v)
    (or (number? v) (null? v)))
  (list 'quote 
        (let recur ((obj obj))
          (if (primitive? obj)
              obj
              (cons (recur (car obj)) 
                    (recur (cdr obj)))))))

(define e (obj->literal d))
e
; ==> (cons (cons 'a (cons 'e (cons 'i (cons 'o (cons 'u 'y))))) (cons 'i (cons 'o (cons 'u 'y))))
(equal? d (eval e (make-base-namespace)))
; ==> #t
```

Comment: Oops. I made a mistake in my code. The loop shouldn't be there. Your code is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your program with `#lang racket` as your language choice,
you need to use the correct namespace with `eval`.

You can for example use this:

```
(define ns (variable-reference->namespace (#%variable-reference)))
(eval e ns)
```

In short: Your macro is working. The example evaluating the result of the macro is not (at least in `#lang racket`).

Note also that there is a difference between using `eval` from "inside a module" and from the REPL. I bet Renzo tested your example in the REPL where it worked correctly and that you tried the example from within the module (that is, in the definition window).

Comment: Yes, namespace is necessary.